# Why is my discord.js channel send throwing an error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to use `discord.js` to send messages to a certain channel. Here is the code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log('ready');
});

const channel = client.channels.cache.get('my id');
channel.send('content');

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

But for some reason it throws this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like the problem is with your channel ID, you should double check it.

Comment: I see no problem with the ID. I just put in "my id" so other people can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`client.channels.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=cache) is empty until the [`Client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) is ready.

To fix your issue, you can place your code into the [`ready`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-ready) event of `Client`.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log('ready');
 const channel = client.channels.cache.get('my id');
 channel.send('content');
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```